# Archiving / Exporting Perforce Streams

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have a perforce Stream

I would like to archive this stream and give it to some one else (a client) at the end of a project so that they can import the stream into their own perforce server.

Can this be done?  Can streams be exported from one serverA/depot1 and then imported into say SomeOtherServer/SomeOtherDepot.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you could use [remote depots](http://kb.perforce.com/article/30).

First, [set up](http://kb.perforce.com/article/694/creating-a-remote-depot) Server1's Depot1 as RemoteDepot1 in Server2, so that Server2 can pull files from Server1.

Then, in Server2, create stream Depot2, and mainline Stream2. Then, while still in Server2, run:

```
p4 populate //RemoteDepot1/Stream1/... //Depot2/Stream2/...
```

This seeds Server2's //Depot2/Stream2 with the files from Server1's //Depot1/Stream1.

Comment: Will the entire history of Stream1 come over to Stream2

Comment: Nope, this is just a snapshot.

Comment: I think the way to achieve this is to copy the depot and then obliterate the streams that you do not need.

Comment: oh. That's not the same as importing the stream into an existing server. If what you need is a stand-alone server that contains only a copy of your stream, P4Sandbox is probably the easiest way. Or so says this post at any rate: http://www.perforce.com/blog/120302/portable-perforce-p4sandbox-usb-stick

Comment: Another possibility is git-p4, which extracts history as well as file content from Perforce into a stand-alone git repo. Then, at the other end, you can use git-p4 to load history+content into another Perforce server. https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git-p4_Usage